# learning closure in javascript and how it works

Tags: javascript, closures

i try to learn closure in JavaScript.

```
let f, g;
function foo() {
  let x;
  f = function() {
    return ++x; };

  g = function() {
    return --x; };

  x = 1;
  console.log('inside foo, call to f(): ' + f());

}
foo();  
console.log('call to g(): ' + g());
console.log('call to f(): ' + f());
```

and i get:

```
inside foo, call to f(): 2
call to g(): 1
call to f(): 2
```

The most confuse me now is, why f() is still 2 at outside of function. Is that what closure do? Could anyone explain this in most simple way. Thanks

Comment: Why does it confuse you? Which value do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing about “why f can visit x even I declared it at outer scope”. It is because JavaScript first initiates a anonymous function inside *foo*, *x* is visible to this function. Then you assign it to the global variable *f*, so it contains the scope of *foo*.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use a global variable in order to hold the total. But keep in mind that this dude will eat you alive if you (ab)use globals.

For scenarios like this, Closure is the best candidate for maintaining state between function calls without using globals. Let’s see how...

```js
(function() {

  function addFn(arg) {

    var total = 0;
    var mul = arg;

    if (total > 5) {
      return function(val) {
        total += val;
        console.log("hello:" + total);
        return total + 9;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("hey:" + mul);
      return function(arg1) {
        mul = mul * arg1;
        console.log("multiply:" + mul);
        return mul;
      };
    }
  };

  var mulcc = addFn(7);
  console.log(mulcc);
  mulcc(2);     // 14
  mulcc(5);     // 70
  mulcc(1);     // 70
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

that's not a closure, really. you need to wrap everything up and only expose the properties that you want to be public - those can retain access to the non-public parts.

do a search for javascript patterns... there are some great references to modules, singletons, etc

Comment: `f` and `g` access a variable that is defined outside of them. How are these not closures?

Comment: They're all defined in the scope of the function foo. because they're at the top level (scope) of that function, any other function defined alongside of them will have access to them. If you defined variables inside each of those functions, they'd be inside those closures and unavailable anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo();  //2
foo();  //2
foo();  //2
```

if only call first time `foo();` then output will be inside foo, call to f(): 2

Second time `foo();` then output will be inside foo, call to `f(): 2`

because each function in declare in memory then use

but when you use as `f();` after using `foo();`

```
console.log('call to f(): ' + f()); //print 3    
console.log('call to f(): ' + f()); //print 4    
console.log('call to f(): ' + f());  //print 5
```

because you have use as closure function `f();` functionality

Comment: f() is still not 2 at outside of function it is incremented.